# how can I classify images in matlab using k-means and ID3 Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, k-means, id3

I have just started using MATLAB. I am supposed to do a project where images have to be classified using k-means and ID3 algorithm .

Consider for example,an animal database. Images have to be classified based on features such as color and texture. These images can later be retrieved by entering the color ,texture and behavior of the animal . The animal with the specified features would be retrieved.
How can i implement this project using MATLAB ? Can i get an explanation of the procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, try to extract features from the images and their corresponding labels. 
Suppose `X` denotes the feature matrix from all images. So, each row of `X` denotes the feature vectors of each samples.

```
opts = statset('Display','final');

k = 2;
startPositions = [0.01 0.01 ; -0.01 -0.01];

[idx,ctrs] = kmeans(X,k,...
                    'Distance','city',...
                    'Options',opts,...
                    'Start',startPositions ...
                );

plot(X(idx==1,1),X(idx==1,2),'r.','MarkerSize',12)
hold on
plot(X(idx==2,1),X(idx==2,2),'b.','MarkerSize',12)
plot(ctrs(:,1),ctrs(:,2),'kx',...
     'MarkerSize',12,'LineWidth',2)
plot(ctrs(:,1),ctrs(:,2),'ko',...
     'MarkerSize',12,'LineWidth',2)
legend('Cluster 1','Cluster 2','Centroids',...
       'Location','NW')
```

The code above here is taken from Matlab documentation.

Now once you have all the examples and their corresponding clusters, you can easily compare the query feature vector with the center of the clusters in terms of some distance metric and take the closest cluster as the result.